# ViewController, tableView and Mapkit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

i'm stuck in the progress of my project because an unusual problem, i added in a ViewController a mapKit and a tableView..the result that i'm looking for is like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGm51.png)

so when the user enter in this page, automatically start a navigation course on the map, based about the parameters of the tableView. I wrote this code to make this happen

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.delegate = self

        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees =  41.869909
        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = 12.512516

        let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 1000;
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)

        let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center), MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)]

        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = "My Position"
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)

  }
```

but the problem is that, the result when the user enter in the above viewController is this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SttkO.png)

as if automatically open the map application; i don't want this, i want my map like a subview of a viewController, i also tried to add some constraints but it did not work because of course it's not my map that gets bigger but rather the view of map application that open above. I would like to know how can i adjust it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You have to code this by your own. You can do this with MKDirections for example or use a framework for that.

You can google "swift turn by turn navigation" or use

[Apple Providing Directions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html) with Map Kit